# Issue in loading dynamic module with Ag-grid in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

we are one of the consumers of Ag-Grid Enterprise and we have written a wrapper grid around ag-grid to add custom features,  logic and reusability as per our company specifications and released as a node module.

One of our main requirement, that we are trying to address now is to receive components built by consumers (defined in their project) dynamically, feed it to our wrapper grid and internally feed it to ag-grid in the way it expects.

Below is the code snippet which explains it more.

**Consumer apps / AppModule.ts**

1. This below snippet is form a consumer project AppModule.ts, where they import our library using ParentModule.forRoot(manifest). The manifest is an array of routes of their components.
2. Manifest object has 3 attributes - componentId, path and loadChildren which are specific to a component in the consumer app. There can be multiple objects in manifest pointing to different components.

```js
const manifests: DynamicComponentManifest[] = [
  {
    componentId: 'message-icon',
    path: 'dynamic-message-icon-editors', // some globally-unique identifier, used internally by the router
    loadChildren: './dynamic-modules/message/message.module#MessageModule',
  }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ParentModule.forRoot(manifests),
  ]
})
```

**Library / ParentModule.ts**

1. The manifest is then read in forRoot static method of our library in order to resolve the routes, DynamicComponentLoader service and DYNAMIC_COMPONENT_MANIFEST InjectionToken.
2. ParentModule also imports gridModule which imports AG-GRID module.

•

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        gridModule  // grid module is where Ag-grid is used
    ],
    exports: [ParentComponent],
    declarations: [ParentComponent],
    providers: [ParentComponentService, CommonServices, GRIDCONFIG],
    bootstrap: [ParentComponent]

})

export class ParentModule {
    constructor(){}
    static forRoot(manifests: DynamicComponentManifest[]): ModuleWithProviders {

        return {
            ngModule: ParentModule,
            providers: [
                DynamicComponentLoader,
                { provide: NgModuleFactoryLoader, useClass: SystemJsNgModuleLoader },
                // provider for Angular CLI to analyze
                { provide: ROUTES, useValue: manifests, multi: true },
                // provider for DynamicComponentLoader to analyze
                { provide: DYNAMIC_COMPONENT_MANIFESTS, useValue: manifests },
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

**Library / DynamicComponentLoader.ts**

- This is the service call to fetch component factory

```js
import { DYNAMIC_COMPONENT, DYNAMIC_COMPONENT_MANIFESTS, DynamicComponentManifest } from './dynamic-component-manifest';
    
    export class DynamicComponentLoader {
        constructor(
        @Inject(DYNAMIC_COMPONENT_MANIFESTS) private manifests: DynamicComponentManifest[],
        private loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
        private _injector: Injector,
        private _compiler: Compiler) {}
    
    /** Retrieve a ComponentFactory, based on the specified componentId (defined in the DynamicComponentManifest array). */
    
    getComponentFactory<T>(componentId: string, _injector?: Injector): Observable<ComponentFactory<T>> {
      const manifest = this.manifests
        .find(m => m.componentId === componentId);
      if (!manifest) {
        return ObservableThrow(`DynamicComponentLoader: Unknown componentId "${componentId}"`);
      }
    
      const p = this.loader.load(manifest.loadChildren)
        .then(ngModuleFactory => {
          const moduleRef = ngModuleFactory.create(_injector || this._injector);
          const dynamicComponentType = moduleRef.injector.get(DYNAMIC_COMPONENT);
          if (!dynamicComponentType) {
            throw new Error(
              `DynamicComponentLoader: Dynamic module for componentId "${componentId}" does not contain DYNAMIC_COMPONENT as a provider.`,
            );
          }
    
          return moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<T>(dynamicComponentType);
        });
    
      return ObservableFromPromise(p);
    }
```

**Library / Grid Module.ts**
•   In gridModule we are trying to make a service call to fetch components factory which in turn can be fed to AgGridModule.

```
export function init_app(dynamicComponentLoader?: DynamicComponentLoader) {
    return dynamicComponentLoader.getComponentFactory()
        .subscribe(components => {
            const dynamicComp = components;

        }, error => {
            console.warn(error);
        });
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        AgGridModule.withComponents(init_app), // this accepts array of components
    ],
    exports: [GridComponent],
    declarations: [GridComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: [GridApiService],
    bootstrap: [GridComponent]

})


export class parentModule {
    constructor() {}
}
```

**Problem:**

We want our consumers to define their components to be passed to ag-grid via the manifest and pass it to our library, which we can resolve and pass it to ag-grid at compile time. However we feel due to the angular lifecycle of loading modules, the `AgGridModule.withcomponents()` is executing ahead of our `ParentModule.forRoot(manifests)`. This flow is not loading the ag-grid as it is not getting the components at the compile time.
How do we address this issue, so that our ParentModule is loaded first and is ready with consumer apps’ components and then pass to `AgGridModule.withcomponents()`?

Comment: Did you ever receive any help on this by ag-grid? We are currently evaluating if we should buy ag-grid and it would be interesting to know how they handle such complex support requests / questions.

Comment: Hi oocx, for this particular issue we dint receive any help from ag-grid, as it was something to deal angular behavior as well, but they fixed on of the issue we faced in their subsequent release pipeline. we had enterprise version license.